# TinyMCE: Formatting my tinymce editor kills django functionality

Tags: javascript, django, tinymce

I have embedded a tinymce form into a django app.  I followed some online tutorials and it worked fine in its basic default setting.  The only problem was that the tinymce form didn't look the way I wanted.  So I added some javascript to add more buttons to move them to the top of the tinymce area.

When I add in the javascript the form doesn't work.  That is my new edits are not transmitted back to the server when I click the SAVE button.

The following renders the tinymce form:

```
 <form action="/edit_document/{{ current_doc.id }}/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
   Name: {{ form.name }} <p>
   {{ form.content }}
   <input type="submit" value="SAVE" />
 </form>
```

The above code works until I add the following javascript to format my tinymce editor.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> tinyMCE.init({  
    mode: "textareas",  
    theme: "advanced",  
    plugins: "advhr,table,emotions,media,insertdatetime,directionality", 
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",  
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top", 
    theme_advanced_buttons1:"bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,sub,sup,separator,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,separator,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect", 
    theme_advanced_buttons2:"bullist,numlist,outdent,indent,ltr,rtl,separator,link,unlink,anchor,image,separator,table,insertdate,inserttime,advhr,emotions,media,charmap,separator,undo,redo", 
    theme_advanced_buttons3: "",  
    content_css: "images/style.css",  
    height: "350px", 
    width: "653px"  
    });  
</script>
```

What happens now is that the `form.content` is not passed back to the django view, rather I get the original content minus any new edits.

What could be happening here?  How can I fix it?

---

After much trial and error, here is the solution.   Do not put the script at the top of the web page to format tinymce elements.  Instead build a special widget that formats the widget. Even thought the script is the same it makes a difference to how django interprets the field.

Comment: i do not understand what you changed after you had it work, what is the difference

Comment: I simply added the javascript to the top of my html file.  Without the javascript it works fine.  With the javascript it doesn't work.  I don't understand how adding that block of javascript breaks the django functionality?

Answer (score 2):

After much trial and error, here is the solution. Do not put the script at the top of the web page to format tinymce elements. Instead build a special widget that formats the widget. Even thought the script is the same it makes a difference to how django interprets the field.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead of using `{{ form.content}}`:

```
{{ form.content|safe }}
```

Hope it helps.